# how to create index to speed up data retrieval

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have this query below it gets 6000+ row of items from the server the downloaded data is only 317KB but it takes almost 25 seconds or the IIS server time out.

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 0
DECLARE @p1 NVarChar(1000) = 'sample.user'
DECLARE @p2 Int = 0
DECLARE @p3 NVarChar(1000) = 'sample.user'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[DocNumber], [t0].[DocStatus], [t0].[Title], [t0].[SubmittedDate], [t0].[CreatedBy], [t0].[ApprovedByStep], [t0].[RoutedFor], 
    (CASE 
        WHEN [t2].[test] IS NULL THEN NULL
        ELSE [t2].[ApprovedBy]
     END) AS [HistApprovedBy]
FROM [TESTDB].[dbo].[SampleTable] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS [test], [t1].[RequestId], [t1].[DocType], [t1].[ApprovedBy]
    FROM [TESTDB].[dbo].[SampleHistories] AS [t1]
    ) AS [t2] ON ([t0].[Id] = [t2].[RequestId]) AND (@p0 = [t2].[DocType])
WHERE ([t0].[CreatedBy] = @p1) OR (([t0].[DocStatus] <> @p2) AND ([t0].[CreatedBy] <> @p3))
ORDER BY [t0].[DocNumber]
```

I read that indexing can speed up data retrieval, how do I create an index of the sql query above? and if you any suggestions on how to speed it up. I would appreciate it.

Click [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkERDxx3E) for the action plan

For reference Below is my LINQ

```
var vm = (from splTbl in SampleTable
      join splsplHist in SamplesplHistories on
      new
      {
          Key1 = splTbl.Id,
          Key2 = 0
      }
      equals
      new
      {
          Key1 = splHist.RequestId,
          Key2 = splHist.DocType
      }
      into subsplHists
      from subsplHist in subsplHists.DefaultIfEmpty()
      where (splTbl.CreatedBy == "sample.user")
            || (splTbl.DocStatus != 0 && splTbl.CreatedBy != "sample.user")
      orderby splTbl.DocNumber
      select new
      {
          splTbl.Id,
          splTbl.DocNumber,
          splTbl.DocStatus,
          splTbl.Title,
          splTbl.SubmittedDate,
          splTbl.CreatedBy,
          splTbl.ApprovedByStep,
          splTbl.RoutedFor,
          splHistApprovedBy = (subsplHist == null ? null : subsplHist.ApprovedBy)
      }
    ).ToList()
    .GroupBy(x => new {
        x.Id,
        x.DocNumber,
        x.DocStatus,
        x.Title,
        x.SubmittedDate,
        x.CreatedBy,
        x.ApprovedByStep,
        x.RoutedFor
    }).Select(x => new
    {
        x.Key.Id,
        x.Key.DocNumber,
        x.Key.DocStatus,
        x.Key.Title,
        x.Key.SubmittedDate,
        x.Key.CreatedBy,
        x.Key.ApprovedByStep,
        x.Key.RoutedFor,
        splHistApprovedBy = string.Join(",", x.Where(i => i.splHistApprovedBy != null).Select(i => i.splHistApprovedBy).Distinct())
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Some thoughts on the SQL: Your CASE statement isn't needed. If `[test]` is null, then `[ApprovedBy]` will be too, so just select `[t2].[ApprovedBy]`. After that, you no longer need to outer join to a sub query that does nothing except add `[test]` to the rows. Just outer join to `[SampleHistories]`. 

It looks like the access plan has a recommendation already.

Comment: If you look at the plan there is a comment "Missing Index" - so the first thing to try is creating that index. The script to create it is there, all you have to do it give it a name.

Comment: @Ben Hi Ben, I need items from [t0] that does not have [t1] to still be selected.

Comment: Yes, an outer join will do that. There's no need for the sub query.

Comment: @Ben I'll also add my LINQ for reference. On my LINQ, [HistApprovedBy] will have a string join of [ApprovedBy] if they are not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Dale Burelle

I created the following index that was suggested by the action plan.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<TransacList, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[Histories] ([DocType])
INCLUDE ([RequestId],[ApprovedBy])
```